# Increasing the brightness level for .continuousAutoExposure Mode

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I implemented a custom camera with the `AVCaptureDevice.Preset.High` preset and I'm using `.continuousAutoExposure`. Everything works as expected, however, the brightness of the picture is sometimes quite low.

I have researched the official documentation and found out, that I am able to set a custom ISO with `setExposureModeCustomWithDuration`. Unfortunately, doing it this way results in the loss of the wished automation of the exposure.

My question now is, is there a way to increase the overall brightness Percentage of the `.continuousAutoExposure` Mode? I need it to increase the exposure to around 5% only, but I also need to stick with the `.continuousAutoExposure` mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to set `exposureTargetOffset` property of the `AVCaptureDevice` instance. You need to use KVO to observe changes in the value of `captureDevice.exposureTargetOffset` and change it to your required exposure level. For more details, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819515/ios-camera-manual-exposure-duration-but-auto-iso).

Comment: This is the solution to the answer. Unfortunately, I did not manage to fully implement it, because my development skills are lacking. Thanks a lot for the resources, the bounty has been distributed.