# Why I can not get auto change exposure duration when set exposureMode is AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturedevice, exposure

I'm developing a photo capture app, and want when the light is low to auto set exposure duration auto down, so I search the API [AVCaptureExposureMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureexposuremode?language=objc), and API said when exposureMode set to `AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExposure` or `AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure` the device will automatically adjusts the exposure levels. But when I move iPad(`Apple/iPad Pro 10.5-inch iOS(12.1.1)`) light to dark, there just change `iso` not change `exposure duration`.

> Sorry for my English... : (

Here is I tried:

- [set `sessionPreset` to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26227)
- invoke `setExposurePointOfInterest` before `setExposureMode`
- my iPad is not support `lowLightBoost`
- set `device.activeMaxExposureDuration` to `device.activeFormat.maxExposureDuration`

```c
        if (![device lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
            if (error) {
                // on error
            }
            return;
        }
        if([device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure]){
            [device setExposureMode: AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure];
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
```

I expect when I move iPad light to dark, the `exposure duration` and `iso` will both auto adjusting.

Comment: I found [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014578-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29930260/7609226), and I will try...

Comment: I tried, it sames work well, but it still sometimes quick flash, so I use this [algorithm](https://rechneronline.de/exposure/), and the quick flash is going down.